# Adding an annotation to the map when a selection is made xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, database, xcode, dictionary

I'm fairly new to xcode and I am currently working a small iPhone app.

I have got the map to show up upon load (Using MKMapView) and also have a button that loads a view that has the ability to show a database. It will display a list of buildings.

My aim is to have it so that when the user touches a buildings name in the second view, the app will drop a pin (and/or annotation) onto the map view on top of the building that has been touched.

How would i go about completing this?

Also, how should I store the Latitude & Longitude in the database so it is related to the correct building name?

I had a look around on here and googled it abit an did not find anything useful, I may have just missed it however.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

I can post my code for the MKMapview if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `addAnnotation:` method in `MKMapView` class. You need to create a new `MKAnnotation` instance, fill it up with relevant information, and add it to your map on button touch.

If you override the `viewForAnnotation:` method on your `MKMapView`, you can animate the pin drop simply by setting the `animatesDrop` property to `YES`.

Check out the [MKMapView Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) for more info.

As for the second part of your question, I'm not really sure what the layout of your database is, or what the exact issue might be there.